# Return a Variable In To HAML

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I was wondering if theres a way to return a ruby variable into a haml file with sinatra. For examply

haml:

```
%b
  = variable
```

Ruby

```
get '/' do
  variable = "foobar"
  haml :filename
end
```

and then have the haml file return with

**foobar**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set it as an instance variable.

```
get '/' do
  @variable = "foobar"
  haml :filename
end
```

And your haml:

```
=@variable
```

Comment: hours of googling and pouring through api's, you would think that would be somewhere. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in a hash of locals to your template:

```
get '/local' do
  haml :filename, :locals => {:variable => "foobar"}
end
```

Now in your template, `variable` will be a variable with the value `"foobar"`.

A possible alternative might be to use a helper method:

```
helpers do
  def variable
    "foobar"
  end
end
```

Now in your template `variable` will be a (badly named) method that returns `"foobar"`.

Comment: I think it's a beautiful name. Thanks for your answer, very helpful.